# Display login popup to users in wordpress on "Read more" click in posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am pretty much new to wordpress. In my posts I have a "read more" anchor tag which I have included as part of the post content . If the user clicks that and if they are not logged in yet , I want to show them a popup which displays the usual wordpress login form. I found no way to figure out whether the user is logged in or not at the client side or in the edit post window.

How to solve this?

Comment: Figure it out on the server side, and then write it into the output in some way/form where it is readable to your client-side JS.

Comment: Can you give the name of a specific file where I can figure that out ?

Comment: Do some basic research: https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress%20function%20check%20if%20user%20is%20logged%20in

Comment: Its just that I dont understand which file is doing what. I found the function in pluggable.php but when I made an ajax request to that file and returned the login status , it showed the fatal error upon site load. What to do ?

Comment: That file only provides the function definition - you need to _call_ the function, elsewhere. Since you want to implement functionality around the post content, the place to do this would probably be in the template(s) that handles that. Which one(s) that would be, depends on your theme.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I have accomplished that :)